# undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007ffc976cb9e8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I am running features tests with Rspec and Capybara.

I have no problem when I add attachments to an existing article on the browser...
But when I run the test, that fails and I don't understand what is happening...
What is the problem?

that is the full error:

```
Failures:

  1) managing article The admin is logged in add images for an article
     Failure/Error: flash[:error] = "Failed uploading attachments" unless @article.save

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007ffc976cb9e8>
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb:130:in `remove_previous'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/carrierwave-1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:349:in `remove_previously_stored_attachments'
     # ./app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-l2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:29:in `request'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:266:in `process_request'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:129:in `custom_request'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-test-1.1.0/lib/rack/test.rb:66:in `post'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:75:in `process'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:42:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:33:in `submit'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/form.rb:46:in `submit'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb:69:in `click'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:154:in `block in click'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:82:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:154:in `click'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:58:in `click_button'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:728:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /Users/bill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/capybara-3.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/managing_article_spec.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is a piece of my failing test:

```
    scenario "add images for a guitar"  do
        guitar = articles(:gibson)
        visit article_path(guitar)

        click_on "Add pictures"

        within "#label_uploader_2" do 
            within "#span_uploader_2" do 
                attach_file("article[attachments][]" , Rails.root.join("spec/assets/images/img_2.jpg"))
            end
        end


        click_on "Update Finished guitar"

        expect(page).to have_content("Picture was successfully added")
    end
```

And here is my attachments controller

```
 class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_article

   def create
    add_more_attachments(attachments_params[:attachments])
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: "Picture was successfully added"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed uploading attachments"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    remove_attachments_at_index(params[:id].to_i)
    if @article.save 
      redirect_to @article, notice: "Picture was successfully destroyed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Failed deleting attachments"
    end
  end

  private

  def set_article
    @article = FinishedGuitar.find(params[:article_id])
  end

  def add_more_attachments(new_attachments)
    attachments = @article.attachments 
    attachments += new_attachments
    @article.attachments = attachments
  end

  def remove_attachments_at_index(index)
    remain_attachments = @article.attachments # copy the array
    deleted_attachments = remain_attachments.delete_at(index) # delete the target attachments
    deleted_attachments.try(:remove!) # delete attachments from S3
    @article.attachments = remain_attachments # re-assign back
  end

  def attachments_params
    params.require(:article).permit({attachments: []}) # allow nested params as array
  end
end
```

### EDIT

if I remove the line `attachments` in my fixtures, the tests are green... The idea is to test the adding of pictures. 
Maybe I haven't set my tests the good way

my fixture for articles.yml

```
gibson:
  title: Gibson Les Paul
  description: Une jolie description pour une jolie guitare.
  attachments: <%= Rails.root.join("spec/assets/images/img_2.jpg") %>
```

here are my db logs just after running the test:

```
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
Started POST "/articles/1072060877/attachments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-11 23:03:45 +0200
Processing by AttachmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "article"=>{"attachments"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fc76d6838a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20180911-67380-ir0qv2.jpg>, @original_filename="img_2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[attachments][]\"; filename=\"img_2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: 232558\r\n">]}, "commit"=>"Update article", "article_id"=>"1072060877"}
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1072060877], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Article Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "articles" SET "attachments" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "articles"."id" = $3  [["attachments", "[null,\"img_2.jpg\"]"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-11 21:03:45.472070"], ["id", 1072060877]]
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 172ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: show the logs, especially the db logs

Comment: Also please show whatever `articles(:gibson)` is returning -- I'm guessing it's malformed.

Comment: it's a fixture `articles(:gibson)`

Comment: @Anthony how do I find the db logs? what is the command?

Comment: `tail -f log/test.log` is typically where they go for rails.  Just run your one spec and give us the output

Comment: @Anthony I updated with the db logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you are supporting multiple attachments on your article but in your fixture you're assigning a single string to attachments rather than an array containing a single string.  Try changing your fixture to

```
gibson:
  title: Gibson Les Paul
  description: Une jolie description pour une jolie guitare.
  attachments: [<%= Rails.root.join("spec/assets/images/img_2.jpg") %>]
```

Comment: that was the array ! gosh how did I miss this :(  thank you !!